# Call PageFactory.InitElements in parallel running tests

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

How do I call `PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this)` when running tests in parallel? Do I need to : Hooks in my Page classes? Should I be passing the driver to the Page in my test with something like:

```
    Login pgLogin = PageFactory.InitElements(driver, Login.class);
```

I doubt that I am the first person to build a framework using Page Object Model + Page Factory + C# + NUnit3 for testing in Parallel on Selenium Grid.. but can't find many examples. Most are very simplistic, depicting driver-setup and a test in one method, but when adding complexity through multiple tests and referencing objects from a Page.cs, additional logic is needed that I just don't know.

Code below:

[Login.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyEQ0.png)

[Test.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqK1q.png)

[Base.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkt5x.png)

[Hooks.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEoUp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the driver object to the page object class :

**Test method look like** :

```
WebDriver driver;
public void yourTest(){
  Login login = new Login(driver);
  your rest of the code ......
}
```

**Page object class :**

```
class Login{
 WebDriver driver;
 public Login(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.InitElements( this.driver, this);
    ............... your code
  }
 // required page elements like txtEmail.
}
```